# *-algebra representation, explicit calculation

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras

suppose we are given a vector space basis of a unital  *-algebra $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{M}_d(\mathbb{C})$. I found a proof showing that one can find a unitary $U$ such that 
$$U\mathcal{A}U^* = \bigoplus_{k} \mathcal{M}_{d_k} \otimes \mathbb{1}_{m_k} $$
where $\mathbb{1}_{m_k}$ is the identity in $\mathcal{M}_{m_k} $ and the dimensions on the right hand side add up to d.

Is it possible to calculate $U$ explicitly?
The proof I found involves minimal projections in the center of $\mathcal{A}$ but I don't even know if it's possible to calculate the center of the algebra.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "explicitly". You are not giving $\mathcal A$ explicitly (note that the basis in your first sentence plays absolutely no role in the rest of the question).

Comment: Yes you are given $\mathcal{A}$ explicitly because you have a vector space basis. And this is the reason I mentioned the basis.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect to obtain information about an algebra from a vector space basis . For instance, your algebra could be  $\mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C \subset M_2 (\mathbb C)$, $d=2$, and your basis $$\begin {bmatrix}57&0\\0&58\end {bmatrix},\ \ \ \begin {bmatrix}-\sqrt2&0\\0&\pi\end {bmatrix}. $$ Then $U $ could be the identity, or $$U=\begin {bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-i\end {bmatrix} , $$ or $$U=\begin {bmatrix}0&\frac {1+\sqrt3}2\\ i&0\end {bmatrix}, $$ or another of an infinity of choices.

Comment: At least you could find a $U$ in your example even though there are infinitely many. Do you claim that it is not possible to provide an algorithm calculating the transformation in general (if the only information you are given is a vector space basis and the fact that this vector space basis generates a vector space which is a *-algebra)? What information do you need to make explicit calculation possible in the general case?

Comment: As you said in your question,  the key piece of information are the minimal central projections. I don't immediately see an obvious way to find them from a linear basis.